# How to JOIN without a relationship in Doctrine?

Tags: php, join, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Log` (table `log`) with members `resourceType` and `resourceId` (with columns `resource_log` and `resource_id`). The `resourceType` can e.g. `Order` (for actions on orders, e.g. status changes ) or `Whatever` (for `Whatever` related actions). There is no relationships (neither in Doctrine, nor in the database) between the `Log` and the "resource" entities/tables.

Now I want to select only the `Log`s, that are related to `Order`s with `myOrderProperty = "someValue"`. That means:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `log`
JOIN
    `order` ON `order`.`id` = `log`.`resource_id` AND `log`.`resource_type` = 'order'
WHERE
    `order`.`my_order_property` LIKE '%my_order_property_value%'
```

But the code

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('l')->from(Log::class, 'l');
$queryBuilder->join('l.order', 'o');
...
$queryBuilder
    ->where('o.myOrderProperty = :myOrderProperty')
    ->setParameter('myOrderProperty', $myOrderProperty);
```

doesn't work, since the entity `Log` doesn't have any relationship with the `Order` (though it has a property `order`):

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 102 near 'o WHERE o.myOrderProperty': Error: Class MyNamespace\Log has no association named order
```

**How to `JOIN` without a relationship defined between two entities?**

<sub>I know, I could use [inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). But semantically it's not an inheritance case. So is there another way for solving the problem?</sub>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `JOIN` without relationship can be implemented like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('l')->from(Log::class, 'l');
$queryBuilder->join(
    Order::class,
    'o',
    \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
    'o.id = l.resourceId'
);
...
$queryBuilder
    ->where('o.myOrderProperty = :myOrderProperty')
    ->setParameter('myOrderProperty', $myOrderProperty);
```

The only problem is, that the joined entities are not added to the main entity, so that `$myLog->getOrder(...)` returns `null`.