# Doctrine : SELECT a relationned entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I have 2 entities :

- LinkServInfra
- Serv

LinkServInfra entity :

- id
- serv (relation OneToOne to Serv)
- infra (ManyToOne to another entity)

Now, I'd like to get a list of Serv based on infra.

So I tried in LinkServInfraRepository :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('DISTINCT s.serv')
            ->where('s.infra = :infra')
            ->setParameter('infra', $infra);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And I get an error :

```
    [Semantical Error] near 'serv FROM': Error: InvalidPathExpression. 
     Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

(I tried first without DISTINCT and tried with it based on answer found here).

The query seems to be good because it's :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT s.serv 
    FROM MyBundle\Entity\LinkServInfra s 
    WHERE s.infra = :infra
```

How would you do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use **DISTINCT on a relation**, only for the **root entity alias**.

You should use **Serv** entity as root and join with **LinkServInfra** and **infra** entity through the 2nd. Something like:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Serv::class)->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('DISTINCT s')
        ->leftJoin("s.linkServInfra", "lsi")
        ->leftJoin("lsi.infra", "infra")
        ->where('infra.id = :infra')
        ->setParameter('infra', 1);
```

Alternatively, if the relation is **unidirectional** and **you do not want to make it bidirectional**, you can use a custom join:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

$qb = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Serv::class)->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('DISTINCT s')
        ->leftJoin(LinkServInfra::class, "lsi", Join::WITH, 'lsi.serv = s')
        ->leftJoin("lsi.infra", "infra")
        ->where('infra.id = :infra')
        ->setParameter('infra', 1);
```

### References

- [How to JOIN without a relationship in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900627/how-to-join-without-a-relationship-in-doctrine)

Comment: Serv don't know the relation (I need to do that for some reasons...) so `s.linkServInfra` don't exist, right ?

Comment: Yes, you have a unidirectional relation. You can make it a bidirectional. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: Yeah but I don't want it to be bidirectional (like I said for some reasons but that's another discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Since the relation is ONLY in LinkServInfra and not in Serv :

I used the relation in LinkServInfra to do it...

```
    public function filter($type, $etat, $infra){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $qb->where(' l.infra = :infra ')
       ->setParameter('infra', $infra);

    if( $type || $etat ){
       $qb->join('l.serv', 's')
       //where & setParameter for type
       //where & setParameter for detail
    }
```

And then where I call the function `filter` :

```
    $entities = $em->getRepository('linkServInfra')->filter(//...
    $servs = array();
    foreach($entities as $entity){
        $servs[] = $entity->getServ();

    }
```

I guess it's not the cleanest solution but it's working...