# Doctrine left join with priority on language field with querybuilder

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine, left-join, query-builder

I'm using the query below:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
    ->select('ad.id, ad.title, ad.year, ad.hours, ad.status')
    ->addSelect('rem.remark')
    ->leftJoin('ad.remark', 'rem', Join::WITH, "rem.language = 'NL'")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

This query is working fine and returns the remark of a ad in the Dutch language. The ad has a one-to-many relation with its remark.

Only I also have ads that have for example an English remark and not a Dutch one. The I will like to get the English remark of that one and on the others in the list still the Dutch remark. So too summarise making a priority list on the languages that are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use an **extra [join without relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900627/how-to-join-without-a-relationship-in-doctrine)**:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
    ->select('ad.id, ad.title, ad.year, ad.hours, ad.status')
    ->addSelect('rem.remark')
    ->leftJoin('ad.remark', 'rem', Join::WITH, "rem.language = 'NL' OR rem.language = 'EN'")
    ->leftJoin(Remark::class, 'customRem', Join::WITH, 
    "rem.id <> customRem.id 
    AND rem.ad = customRem.ad 
    AND customRem.language = 'NL'")
    ->where('customRem.id IS NULL')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

The idea is

- if NL language remark exists for an ad, add this remark joined to each result row of this ad expect to itself(will be null)
- if NL language remark does not exist and an EN exists, then the joined row will be null

Finally, the condition `customRem.id IS NULL` makes this work.

**Multiple languages solution**

In the case of 3 supported languages, because **DE > EN > NL**, you could do:

```
->leftJoin(Remark::class, 'customRem', Join::WITH,        
     "rem.id <> customRem.id AND rem.ad = 
      customRem.ad AND rem.language < customRem.language")
```

For multiple languages and suppose a "**customized**" ability to order the languages, you could use:

```
"rem.id <> customRem.id 
AND rem.ad = customRem.ad AND 
(case when rem.language = 'NL' THEN 3 " .
"when rem.language = 'EN' THEN 2 " .
"when rem.language = 'DE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) < (case when customRem.language = 'NL' THEN 3 " .
"when customRem.language = 'EN' THEN 2 " .
"when customRem.language = 'DE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"
```

Alternatively, you could create **"lang_position" table**(id, language, position) and join twice to get the position from the language.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer and basically it works. Only one thing is not working correctly and you could not know this as i did not explain it property. We have 3 languages, so also DE. So I changed your code to: rem.language = 'NL' OR rem.language = 'EN' OR rem.language = 'DE' . Only when we have an Ad without NL but with EN and DE we get the add back twice as of the 2 alternative languages. Can we and an max of 1 on the join or an other solution?

Comment: @Tom in this case because DE > EN > NL, you could do: `->leftJoin(Remark::class, 'customRem', Join::WITH, 
    "rem.id <> customRem.id 
    AND rem.ad = customRem.ad 
    AND rem.language < customRem.language")` , I will try to update the answer and offer a more generic solution to be able to order to selection.

Comment: Thanks Jannes, it works great. Small typo, thread need to be changed in ad.